# How can I insert a value in my table with special condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I want to save String div value in my table column named `BASKET`. But it should be stored a row where id column is str which is given by session attribute.
The variables `str` and `div` do have values. An error message is ORA-00933 which is about sql query I think.
Does the query I've written have some problems? Please let me know how I can handle it.

```
<%
    session.getAttribute("id");
    String str = session.getAttribute("id").toString();
        String div = request.getParameter("div");

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstmt = null; 



try{
    String jdbcDriver = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    String dbUser = "scott";
    String dbPass = "1111";

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcDriver,dbUser,dbPass);
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
        "insert into NEW_MEMBER(BASKET) values(?) where id = str "); 

    pstmt.setString(1, div);


    pstmt.executeUpdate();


}finally{
    if(pstmt!=null)try{pstmt.close();}catch(SQLException ex){}
    if(conn!=null)try{conn.close();}catch(SQLException ex){}
}

%>
```

Comment: Your insert query makes no sense.  A `VALUES` based insert can't take a `WHERE` clause.  You _could_ use a `WHERE` clause if you were doing an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM`, but, you're not doing that.  Please explain what your intended logic is here.

Comment: @jamess I think you should use update if you are trying to write to an existing row

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  There are 2 columns in my table ID and BASKET. so I want to insert div value in basket column where ID column name is str. I think there is some big mistake in my query but have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: @klvenky I have tried update query but it has not worked well.

Comment: Unrelated, but: connection handling or running SQL should **not** be done inside a JSP page. Use a Servlet and a proper connection pool for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an *update* here:

```
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE NEW_MEMBER SET BASKET = ? WHERE id = ?"); 

pstmt.setString(1, div);
pstmt.setString(2, str);
```

As I mentioned in the comments, it only makes sense to use a `WHERE` clause with an insert if you are using another table for the insert.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood using update and insert query. Thanks a lot!